# startActivityForResult + ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS

Tags: kotlin, android-10.0

Firstly: I was looking for an answer but didn't found it here neither in Google.

When I run this code (in kotlin and on Android 10):

`startActivityForResult(Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS),Uri.parse("package:" + packageName)), 55)`

It ends with exception:

`android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS dat=package:dantem.im }`

**But** this code works without any problems:

`startActivityForResult(Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:" + packageName)), 200)`

This code works too, but it show list of all packages which I don't want:

`startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS))`

Where is problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation for `ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS) says that it takes no input. That is why you will find that many, if not all, Android devices give you the `ActivityNotFoundException` — your `Uri` on the `Intent` causes that `Intent` to not match any `<intent-filter>`.

Comment: "<intent-filter>" - Is it a matter of the operating system? Can I influence it in any way? Very frustrated the operating system Android is designed by this way (and I have to use it).

Comment: @mirij: "Is it a matter of the operating system?" -- more accurately, it is the Settings app and what it exposes. This is why many of these actions have, in the documentation, something like "note that not all devices may support this `Intent` action". Beyond what *Google* does, device manufacturers can change the Settings app how they want. "Can I influence it in any way?" -- you can develop your own custom ROM based on your own build of Android and the Settings app. Along the way, you can teach the Settings app to do what you want.